# Как передать в метод (функцию) набор аргументов из массива

Tags: ооп, php, mvc

Имею массив, например:

```
array('1' , '2' , '3');
```

Как передать функции набор аргументов

```
function my('1', '2', '3') {

}
```

Есть функция

```
call_user_func_array
```

Но в моем случае проблема в том, что нужно передать это в метод классу.

```
$class -> my(  ?  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array(array($class, 'my'), array(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Эм-м...Это очень странно, но это работает именно как надо!

Comment: С чего б странно-то?